# Use runtime optimzed JS and CSS resources in XSP Properties causes error

Tags: xpages

In XPages I have enabled the "*Use runtime optimized JS and CSS resources*" but it raises and error:

**inputmask is not a function.**

I have loaded the script as followed:

```
<xp:this.resources>         
    <xp:script
        src="/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"
        clientSide="true">
    </xp:script>     
</xp:this.resources>
```

It works fine when I have the XSP property disabled.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you just add the library as a normal script reference? e.g.

```
<script src="inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then it will be loaded as a separate file